# Удаление картинки при нажатии на нее JS

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который при нажатии на ссылку открывает блок и при этом сама ссылка удаляется - прекрасно работает, если внутри текст, но если там картинка   не срабатывает, что не нравится?

https://jsfiddle.net/hibinyru/1vquoj30/1/

```
.hidden { display: none;}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if( !e.target.matches('.js-show-text') ) return;
  
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('hidden');
  e.target.outerHTML = "";
});

<a class="js-show-text" href="javascript:void(0);">Показать</a>
<span class="hidden">Скрытый текст</span>
<hr>
<a class="js-show-text" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="https://www.hibiny.com/images/2020/interface/ic-close.png"></a>
<span class="hidden">Скрытый-2</span>
```

или может быть подскажите решение тоже самого на jquery ? с учетом что на странице таких блоков может быть несколько

Comment: `.js-show-text img {pointer-events: none;}`

Comment: Спасибо!!! То что нужно

Comment: на самом деле, нет, нужно написать нормальный код, зачем там вообще якорь?

Comment: не знаю, работает и хорошо :)